# python 3 shambles

Tags: apt, updates, python

First of all on my 18.04 LTS machine 
I have Ubuntu update issues , several updates have been botched todays update too, nevertheless my updater says everything is up to date

Iḿ not sure if python is correctly installed / updated

1- How can I get a correct Python installed on my machine because I think other programs are missing parts of this environment and ceased working such as Sweethome 3D (by eteks)
2- where can i find the update logs of my last updates so that i can see what updates have not completed correctly 
3- after locating the logs i will attempt to understand what has happened, i that is not possible who can send I the logs to tell me what has occurred and what needs to be repaired

Comment: Might be more useful to start, what is not working well in your opinion, from terminal and post the output.

Comment: Look at `more /var/log/dpkg.log`.

Comment: You can find your update logs here: `/var/log/apt` It is unlikely that you will find anyone to send your logs to who will analyze them.  You can try returning here to ask more questions, or [edit] this question with specifics.

Comment: The /var/log/apt/history.log  lists for  every update since feb1st  that   Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: The /var/log/apt/history.log  lists for  every update since feb1st  that   
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
The tem. log shows  thart there were too many errors

the first error is  : E: py3compile:183: cannot create directory /usr/share/hplip/ui5/__pycache__: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')

Comment: This problem has been solved see [this article] [1]
[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118809/ubuntu-18-04-python3-dpkg-and-hplib?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking a few things:

```
which python
```

... should point to /usr/bin/python if it is installed properly.  Next check that it defaults to the version you want:

```
python -V
```

As an added check, check that the python command is actually a soft link that points to the version you want and that there is also an associated python config file for that version:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python*
```

If the version is NOT the one you want, delete the soft link:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
```

... and relink it to the version you want - for example if you want version 3.6:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s python3.6 python
```

Create soft links to config files if they are missing. Verify that all went well:

```
python -V
```

Note that you need to install pip for Python 2.7 and pip3 for newer Python versions:

```
sudo apt install pip pip3
```

It's ok to have both pip versions installed at the same time in case you need to go back and forth between Python versions - which you can do by changing the /usr/bin/python soft link as I described above.

One last note - Python3 will find modules you installed with pip3 but not with pip, and Python2.7 will find modules you installed with pip but not with pip3.

Comment: Hell what a mess I dug up here, 
in /use/bin/  i have following directories
*  python
*  python2
*  python2.7    ( which so be the active python version on my machine) 
*  python2.7-config
*  python2-config
*  python2-futurize
*  python2-pasturize
*  python3
*  python3.5
*  python3.5m
*  python3.6
*  python3.6-config
*  python3.6m
*  python3.6m-config
*  python3-config
*  python3m
*  python3m-config
*  python-config

Comment: I can rem all directories  except the python3.6

Comment: sorry its files not directories in /usr/bin/

Comment: On the sudo apt install pip pip3   command 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pip
E: Unable to locate package pip3

Comment: The apt purge hplip.data  and apt purge hplip  ditd the trick 
A lot of pending changes were execute